# Break long lines with no whitespace inside verbatim

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim

I am trying to typeset a long line from CSV file, that contains special characters but no whitespaces. Since I would like it to be visually different from surrounding text, I am using `verbatim` environment. 
The problematic line looks somthing like this:

```
"%TIME_STAMP%","%TIME_SERIES_NAME_(metric)%","%ENTITY%","%FIRST_TAG_VALUE%","%SECOND_TAG_VALUE%","%THIRD_TAG_VALUE%","VALUE"
```

I already tried `verbatim` and `spverbatim` environment (from package `spverbatim`), which worked well with special symbols, but didn't wrap lines (even when I artificially added whitespace just for sake of experimenting). I attempted to use `listings` but presence of special characters made my file impossible to compile (even when I escaped underscores and percent symbols using backslash)

So my question is - how to make latex wrap lines on both whitespace and some special character - like comma - inside environments like verbatim or spverbatim? If it is not possible, would using listings help? If yes, how to escape special characters?

Here is what fails to compile with listings

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3.5cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks,breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel} 

\usepackage{amsthm} 

\usepackage{spverbatim}
\usepackage{listings} %dlhe csv riadky
\lstset{
   breaklines=true,
   basicstyle=\ttfamily}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\linespread{1.25} 


\begin{document}     

\begin{lstlisting}
"%ČASOVÁ_PEČIATKA%","%NÁZOV_ČASOVÉHO_RADU%", "%ENTITA%","%HODNOTA_TAGU%","%ÚDAJ%"
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Usually `listings` does not care about special characters. Could you show us, what you have tried (compilable document)?

Comment: @TeXnician I added the exact string, not just example, because surprisingly, the example one can be compiled. Meybe the special characters like č are causing troubles?

Comment: It's not a problem of TeX characters, but of literal encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added the `literate` key and some (more) special characters.

[image: broken line]

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3.5cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks,breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel} 

\usepackage{amsthm} 

\usepackage{spverbatim}
\usepackage{listings} %dlhe csv riadky
\lstset{
   breaklines=true,
   basicstyle=\ttfamily,
   literate=    {á}{{\'a}}1
{č}{{\v{c}}}1
{ď}{{\v{d}}}1
{é}{{\'e}}1
{ě}{{\v{e}}}1
{í}{{\'i}}1
{ň}{{\v{n}}}1
{ó}{{\'o}}1
{ř}{{\v{r}}}1
{š}{{\v{s}}}1
{ť}{{\v{t}}}1
{ú}{{\'u}}1
{ů}{{\r{u}}}1
{ý}{{\'y}}1
{ž}{{\v{z}}}1
{Á}{{\'A}}1
{Č}{{\v{C}}}1
{Ď}{{\v{D}}}1
{É}{{\'E}}1
{Ě}{{\v{E}}}1
{Í}{{\'I}}1
{Ň}{{\v{N}}}1
{Ó}{{\'O}}1
{Ř}{{\v{R}}}1
{Š}{{\v{S}}}1
{Ť}{{\v{T}}}1
{Ú}{{\'U}}1
{Ů}{{\r{U}}}1
{Ý}{{\'Y}}1
{Ž}{{\v{Z}}}1}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\linespread{1.25} 


\begin{document}     

\begin{lstlisting}
"%ČASOVÁ_PEČIATKA%","%NÁZOV_ČASOVÉHO_RADU%", "%ENTITA%","%HODNOTA_TAGU%","%ÚDAJ%"
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: unfortunately, your code doesn't compile `! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �\lst@FillFixed@ (U+5AA)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.38 "%ČASOVÁ
               _PEČIATKA%","%NÁZOV_ČASOVÉHO_RADU%", "%ENTITA%","%HODNOTA...`

Comment: @filox Does it compile now?

Comment: unfortunately no, still the same exact seme error

Comment: ok, I fixed it by adding characters from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16084246/7378363

Comment: @filox Great, I updated it (I compiled with LuaLaTeX which supports full unicode input, my fault).